# Number Theory Class v2

Tags: mathematics

Inspired from: [Number Theory Class](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/55277/number-theory-class)

Our magician was unhappy because his magic was revealed so fast! so he made another magic and gave a calculator to an audience and said:

> - Pick any number,
> - Multiply it with 23,
> - Take the sum of its digits, let's call it A,
> - Multiply the number you picked again with 67,
> - Take the sum of its digits again, let's call it B,
> - Take the difference of these two numbers as A-B, tell me the result!

The audience member said

> $-11$.

Magician said

> Good, now remove any non-zero digit from your number and tell me the rest, and tell me the rest of digits in any order.

The audience member responded

> $5$ and $2$.

And the magician announced in an instant,

> The number you have removed was $9$.

The magician is right! How?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We use the following deep fact:

> the sum of digits of a positive integer is congruent to the number itself modulo $9$.

Now let the initial number be $x$. Then

> $A\equiv 23x\equiv 5x\pmod{9}$.

Also, we have

> $B\equiv 67x\equiv 4x\pmod{9}.$

Therefore

> $A-B\equiv x\pmod{9}$. This gives the magician the value of sum of digits of $x\pmod9$, so if he gets all but one digits of $x$, he can back-calculate the rest. For example, in the given case, if the remaining digit was $c$, then the magician could reckon that $5+2+c\equiv -11\pmod{9}\implies c\equiv-18\equiv 9\pmod{9}$, and this uniquely determines $c$ since $c$ is non-zero.